# How to erase path drawn on canvas with white color

Tags: android

This Code Works perfect but it erases with black color and I want to erase with white color.

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Please help! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Am also facing the same problem. have u got any answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of erasing with a white color but we can erase without a black color (i.e transparent color will apper while erasing)

Please go through [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16299295/877994).

Answer (score -1):

make an additional path and Paint with the same settigs, set the color of the paint to whatever you want.  set canvas.drawPath(, ); after the PorterDuffXfermode paint  but don't reset the path so the overlay paint wont be saved on touch up.
worked for me.
good luck