# How to change default erase color in paint application in Android?

Tags: android, graphics

I make an Application in which I want to erase drawing lines with event. For this I used

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

but at the time of erasing a line, that line becomes black first then erased. I want a transparent color for erasing a drawing a path.

Comment: I also fetch out that problem.......Can any body help...?

Comment: @user1287756 have u got any solution for that issue.

Comment: I have same issue. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the **`FingerPaint.java`** from **APIDemos**  i.e  `android-sdk\samples\android-17\ApiDemos`

and modified

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

   canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

   mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);  // this line changed 
                                     // mCanvas is Canvas variable which is
                                     // initialized in onSizeChanged()
}
```

Now it is not drawing a black color while erasing, everything works fine. Not sure it is 100% proper answer but it works for me.

Comment: It is definitely wrong since you are drawing the path to a different Canvas instance

Comment: @EyalBellisha actually it does work for me too, because you are drawing to the mCanvas object permanently and only temporarily to the onDraw canvas object, the eraser works on the mCanvas object instantly. If I try to draw the eraser path on the onDraw canvas object it is only applied after I lift my finger up.

Answer (score 0):

The below works for erasing on a transparent background...

Call SetErase(true) to start erasing.

The OnDraw method will then draw a white path (instead of black)which will then get cleared to the transparent color and you keep all your path undo info.

Call SetErase() to toggle erasing on/off

```
    public void SetErase(bool On)
    {
        if (On)
        {
            if (!_erasing)
            {
                _delpaint = new Paint(_paint);
                _delpaint.Color = Color.White; 
                _paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.Clear));
                _erasing = true;
            }
        }
        else if (_erasing)
        {
            _erasing = false;
            _paint.SetXfermode(null);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.DrawColor(BackgroundColor);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(CanvasBitmap, 0, 0, _bitmapPaint);
        if (_erasing)
        {
            canvas.DrawPath(_path, _delpaint); // draw white path
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.DrawPath(_path, _paint);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey I have used a kind of trick to remove the black line.In my erase button, I have set the color to white, instead of using XferMode..

```
if(erase){
paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}
```